# sql in for loop not working

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix, scripting

Im trying to run a script call Interface.sh where a for loop takes values from a file and runs it through a series of sql commands using a here document.

The file (called InterfaceSymbols.ASIA) contains 3 lines of text.

Below is what I have so far.

```
rsh $MACHINE
cd /srg/data/Interface
for line in `cat /srg/data/Interface/InterfaceSymbols.ASIA`
    do  
    sql <<EOF
    select s.symbol, i.inventory
    from
    symbol s,
    inventory i,
    portfolio_inventory pi
    WHERE
    s.portfolio = pi.portfolio AND
    pi.inventory = i.inventory
    and s.symbol = "$line";
    exit
EOF
done
```

When I run the shell script it doesnt work how I anticipate.

it then rsh's over to $MACHINE, then does nothing from there. when I logout of the machine it returns:

```
Inter.sh: line 16: sql: command not found
Inter.sh: line 16: sql: command not found
Inter.sh: line 16: sql: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?? I can see its trying to run the it three times (equivalent to the amount of values in the file).

Comment: It doesn't recognise the sql command, try giving it the full path

Comment: Ok that worked, but now Im getting:

`Enter user-name: SP2-0306: Invalid option.`
    `Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS      {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] [edition=value]]`
    `where <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>]    [@<connect_identifier>]`
    `Enter user-name: Enter password:`
`ERROR:`
    `ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist`

How do I pass the sql log in and password?

Comment: Now it knows what sql is you'll need to tell it which db it's connecting to and supply it with a user id and password. In other words you need to check the syntax for your call to sql.

Comment: Something like sql user_id/password@yourdb

Comment: That worked fine thanks, just one more question - how can I save the output of the looped here document into a separate file? Can't seem to work it out!

Answer (score 0):

Well, that just looks like you don't have `sql` in the path on your remote machine. That's *probably* because `rsh`, in its desire to be safe, limits the path to something like:

```
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

You could confirm this with a command like:

```
rsh otherbox -l username "/usr/bin/echo \$PATH"
```

Easiest fix is probably to give the full file specification for `sql` rather than relying on finding it in your path.

Alternatively, you can use something like:

```
rsh otherbox -l username ". .profile && sql something or other"
```

to source the profile (and hopefully set up a more complete path) before running your command.